# How to write sum(field) as a scripted field in Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4

There is a way to perform simple mathematical calculations in scripted fields such as `doc['A'].value+doc['B'].value`
. Is there a way to find sum as an aggregation like when there are 1000s of values to sum up? For eg. I want to find 
`sum(<a_set_of_values_stored_in_one_field>)`. Similarly, how to find count of a certain field `"count(field_name)"`?

Comment: Add more details. It's a bit unclear what you're asking for.

Comment: I've added more details.

Comment: did you found solution? if yes, please update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

scripted fields only operate on the individual document, and not across all documents. In other words, they don't execute queries themselves. Rather they're intended to be used within queries. So you could execute a query which sums the value of this scripted field across all documents

Answer (score -3):

In the Y-axis, instead of **"count"** chose **"Sum"**, then in the new window that appear, you can chose your field.

PS: This is for sum the value of one field.

Comment: Yes. I'm aware of that. Thank you. But you cannot do further calculations with that right? I mean, what if i want to find the sum(field)/<some_number> in the Y axis.

Comment: I saw your reply now, sorry for this, 
you mean that you want to count just some values of a field? 
It depends on your dataset, for example if you want to sum just the values that are greater than 1000, you can do it, but if they are randomly values, I do not have any idea if it is possible or no!